# How can I get the dimensions of an object using script?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, dimensions

In *Object Mode*, when I press <kbd>N</kbd>, I get a little box called Transform. At the bottom of this box I can see the X,Y,Z dimensions of my mesh. Is there a way to get these dimensions through a Python script?

Like if I just want the Y dimension (height of object) returned, would I do something like:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.Transform.dimensions[1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Some blender basics**

The console is a great place to figure stuff out

[image]

where `C = bpy.context` and `D = bpy.data` for our convenience.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> C.object.dimensions
Vector((2.0000009536743164, 2.0000009536743164, 2.0))

>>> C.object.dimensions.y
2.0000009536743164

>>>
```

The height of an object in blender is its Z dimension.  Blender uses Z up and -Y forward.

The buttons in blender run operators.  In code these start with `bpy.ops`  The translate operator for example is `bpy.ops.transform.translate()`

The python console has autocomplete, hence you can peck around and nut somethings out.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for, thank you

Comment: @batFINGER I can see a `NVim` button in your screenshot. Is it safe to assume that this is a blender addon for NeoVim integration. If yes can you point me to the addon?

Comment: @icalvin102 Correct. Is very much a WIP which relies on a number of 3rd party packages.  If I get around to making some stripped back version (using a lot of gtk3, plumbum, and other 3rd party packages) will upload and give you a hey. Suggest looking at `pynvim` can contact the buffers of open nvim instance and pipe to and from blender quite simply.  Was originally GVim but the nvim API is soooo much better, but the editor is a lot slower. (Been using SpaceVim)  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20753/getting-an-rgb-color-from-highlight-group

Comment: Thank you @batFINGER I'll take a look `pynvim`. If you find the time to make your tool availible that would be very nice.